# Embarrassing Offline Recurring Contributions

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, iats, pending

A bit of an embarrassing situation for us: A recurring credit-card contribution attempted to process last Wednesday (2/21), but our vendor (iATS) did not receive it (I've checked with them, no such record). CiviCRM left the transaction in a Pending:Incomplete Transaction status. The following day(2/22), Civi tried again, and the contribution went through just fine. I thought that was the end of it.

Unfortunately, the contribution processed again each day including this morning (2/27)! The donor notified us, and I took what action I knew to do -- I cancelled the recurring contribution entirely and explained we will of course refund the money. Since iATS still shows no record of the first attempt on 2018-2-21, I also marked the open Pending transaction in Civi as Failed.

**Question 1: That should be the end of it, correct?** Or do I need to do something else?

I'm left trying to figure out what happened, and how to prevent this from happening again.

Curiously, the recurring contribution still had a "Next Scheduled Contribution Date" of `2018-02-21 02:07:31`.  Each of the contributions that went through after the initial Pending attempt had a source of `Offline Recurring Contribution`. We've never had that source automatically before.

**Question 2: Why did the Next Scheduled date not update to next month after the first successful attempt went through?**  (I'm assuming Civi kept charging the card because the Next Sched date was still showing 2018-2-21).

**Question 3: Why would the card try again if the status of the original Pending attempt was still showing Pending and not Failed?**

In hindsight, I think what I should have done was mark the Pending transaction as Failed as soon as I saw the reattempt go through correctly and then made sure the Next Scheduled Date updated to next month. That would have prevented all this theoretically, ya? Now I know.

Thanks for any help!  We're using CiviCRM 4.6 LTS and iATS extension 1.5.3.

Answer (score 2):

Advancing next_scheduled_date is one of the last things that happens in this sequence. So if anything goes wrong - a post_contribution hook eg - then the code can not get to the part where the date is advanced.

So look in your ConfigAndLog for clues as to what interfered with the recording/completion of that Contribution in your database.

Comment: Thank you, Karin. I'll dive into the logs. With the recurring cancelled, the donor's card should no longer get charged, correct?

Comment: If the status of the series is cancelled in CiviCRM the iATS Extension will indeed not submit the token associates with the series to iATS for processing

Comment: Let me know what you find out